# Unable to Hit Api Route in Asp.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. I am adding some APIs to this app. Some of my APIs work. Others do not. The problem I am having is that I do not know either a. what route I should be using or b. if I am not registering the routes properly. For instance, I have the following WebApi:

```
namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    public class ProjectApiController : System.Web.Http.ApiController
    {
        [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Product>))]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(string search, int max)
        {
            // Clean up the query
            string query = q.Trim().ToLower();

            // Get the products
            List<Product> products = Product.GetAll();
            var results = (from product in products
                           where product.Name.ToLower().Contains(query)
                           select new
                           {
                               Id = product.Id,
                               Name = product.Name
                           }).Take(max);

            // Return the results
            return Ok(results);
        }

        [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Category>))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCategories(string search, int max)
        {
            // Clean up the query
            string query = q.Trim().ToLower();

            // Get the products
            List<Category> products = Category.GetAll();
            var results = (from category in categories
                           where category.Name.ToLower().Contains(query)
                           select new
                           {
                               Id = category.Id,
                               Name = category.Name
                           }).Take(max);

            // Return the results
            return Ok(results);
        }
    }
}
```

When I visit `/api/projectApi?search=tes&max=5`, I get back a JSON array like I want, IF the second method is commented out. If the second method is uncommented, I get an error that says the following:

```
"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nGet on type MyProject.Controllers.ProjectApiController\r\nGetCategories on type MyProject.Controllers.PrjectApiController","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"}
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to call:

`/api/projectApi/projects?search=tes&max=5`  AND

```
/api/projectApi/categories?search=tes&max=5
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to do that. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you using ASP.NET api 2 you can also now use route attributes to decorate your methods, eg

```
[Route("/api/projectApi/products")]
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Product>))]
public IHttpActionResult Get(string search, int max)
{ ...
}
```

and

```
[Route("/api/projectApi/categories")]
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Category>))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCategories(string search, int max)
{ ...
}
```

see http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Answer (score 0):

when you call

```
/api/projectApi?search=tes&max=5
```

the routing doesn't know which method to give since you don't specify the action, just the controller and the parameters, which are the same for both method.

To solve that add this routing

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{search}/{max}",
            defaults: new { search = RouteParameter.Optional, max = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

now those routes will work

```
/api/projectApi/Get/tes/5 
/api/projectApi/GetCategories/tes/5
```

Comment: This seems close to what I'm looking for. However, I'm still getting an error. The error is `{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:1081/api/projectApi/categories?search=test&max=3'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'ProjectApi' that matches the name 'categories'."}`

Comment: yes, you didn't read clearly my answer, i say in my answer this route will work : /api/projectApi/GetCategories/tes/5 so 'http://localhost:1081/api/projectApi/GetCategories/tes/5' . For me seems clearer than routes with "?search=test&max=5"

Comment: I understand what you're saying. My challenge is, my code has some third-party controls that insist on passing things via the query string instead of a full route. That's why I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when adding api controllers to my mvc projetct. In my case i was missing this "GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);" in my Global.asax.

Mine looks like this:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```